# R How to change the scale of graph in R

Tags: r, graph

I was wondering how I can change my x axis from what it currently is (Number of measurements) to just time, as it's clear from my code I have the x axis going from 0 to 300000 when I would much rather have it going from 0 to 30.

```
install.packages("smfsb")
library(smfsb)
out = gillespied(LV,T=30,dt=0.0001)
#Plot of 5 realisations of the prey# #First way#
M1 <- out[,1]
for (i in 1:4)  {
        out = gillespied(LV, T=30, dt=0.0001)
        M1 = cbind(M1,out[,1])
}
matplot(M1, type="l", pch="", col="grey",xlab="No. of 
measurements",ylab="No. of Prey", ylim=c(-100,600))
```

So as it shows in the picture, I would like the change the x axis scales. I was wondering if there is a function which can easily do this for me.

Thanks

Edit: Unfortunately I am unable to embed the picture associated with this question, but as I said, the x axis goes from 0 to 300000 instead I want 0 to 30

This is the graph of what I get : https://gyazo.com/f015f9fbf2f6fc3beb7675be488578bc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided sample data but you are using `matplot` so here is an example:

some matrix:

```
   mat <- matrix(rnorm(20), 5)
```

plot without axes

```
matplot(mat, type="l", axes = F)
```

add manual axes

```
axis(side = 1, at = 1:5, labels = c("a", "b", "c", "D" ,"oh man"))
```

result:

[image]

using:

```
matplot(mat, type = "l", xaxt = 'n')
```

will just remove the x axis

```
axis(side = 1, at = 1:5, labels = c("a", "b", "c", "D" ,"oh man"))
```

[image]

additional example:

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(10000), 5000)
matplot(mat, type="l", xaxt = 'n')
axis(side = 1, at = (0:10)*1000, labels = 0:10)
```

Comment: Hey man, yeah sorry for not adding the data, but that's only because I make 300,000 measurements and then repeating it 5 times, so you can see how large my matrix M1 was going to be. If I could show you the picture it would be ideal. At the moment I'm getting this error, unexpected numeric constant in "axis(side = 1, at 1",  not sure what it means

Comment: The code that I added was, matplot(M1, type="l", pch="", col="grey", xaxt= 'n', xlab="No. of measurements", ylab="No. of Prey", ylim=c(-100,600))                                 
axis(side = 1, at 1:30, labels = c(1:30))

Comment: Hey, thanks, I was being a fool by missing out that "=" sign. Cheers, this has worked for me and helped me out a lot